# Appending to JSON array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, append

I am looking to append to a JSON array in ruby. The JSON array looks like this:

`{"data" : [{"name":"Chris","long":10,"lat":19}, {"name":"Scott","long":9,"lat":18}]}`

I want to be able to append another object to this array e.g

`{"name":"John","long":20,"lat":45}`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First convert the JSON to a Ruby hash this way:

```
require 'json'
rb_hash = JSON.parse('<your json>');
rb_hash["data"] << { name: "John", long: 20, lat: 45 }

rb_hash.to_json
```

Comment: You can't put the keys of a hash in strings in Ruby, not unless you use the fat arrow `=>`. Your code won't parse. You can fix it by using `{ name: "John", long: 20, lat: 45 }`, or `{ "name" => "John", "long" => 20, "lat" => 45 }`.

Comment: you can't define json like that in ruby. it will give sytax error. it should be as string. if it is a string, JSON.parse will work.

Comment: Wait, how do I then write it to the file?

Comment: @user1614998 I don't mean in the call to `JSON.parse`, I mean where you append to the array. I tested it out using Ruby 1.9.3 and it works like the way I said, it won't work the way you had it originally.

Comment: @Cj1m open up the file in Ruby and replace its contents.

Comment: like this: File.open("public/test.json", "w") do |f|
   f.write(rb_hash) end

Comment: @Cj1m something like that, sure.

Comment: @Cupcake okay, sorry i missed it.

Comment: @Cupcake That doesn't seem to work, here is a paste bin of my code: http://pastebin.com/dyGmMmW7

Comment: @Cj1m try JSON.parse(File.open('<file_path>').read) to read json

Comment: @Saravanan Do you know how I can make "name:" in the JSON script equal to a variable in Ruby e.g var: "John" ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append existing hash, we can do as below-

```
hash = {}
```

I have another hash as-

```
sub_hash = {}
```

then-

```
hash.merge!(sub_hash)
```

will work great!!!